# SQL Server : Is It possible to find/searching data from another server?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, search, find

I want to find/searh some data based on "IDPenerima"(integer) from another server.

Can I do that?

Here is my code.

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=10.9.xxx.xx;Database=source;User ID=username;Password= password";
        string sql = " SELECT * FROM FROMPenerima WHERE IDPenerima = '" + txtfindidpengirim.Text + "'";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        connection.Open();
        dataadapter.Fill(ds2, "Authors_table");
        connection.Close();
        GridPenerima1.DataSource = ds2;
        GridPenerima1.DataMember = "Authors_table";


        DataGridViewColumn column = GetGrid1.Columns[0];
        column.Width = 80;
        DataGridViewColumn column1 = GetGrid1.Columns[1];
        column1.Width = 1500;
        DataGridViewColumn column2 = GetGrid1.Columns[2];
        column2.Width = 80; }
```

Comment: What is your question? What is not working exactly? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Is it possible to find/search data fro  another server? I try with this code to select data and then show at datagrid. it isn't work. maybe my coding wrong? Thank you so much for tell me that parameterized queries. i'm new. :) @SonerGönül

Answer (score 0):

#### Querying 2 databases but on 2 differents servers:

---

- manage yourself in your application (populate objects from 2 queries then check : *not really beautiful*)

OR

- manage by anticipation with an ETL  (ex : [SSIS from Microsoft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services), that would import data from remote server to your local server, so that you query in same server (***best*** when possible)

OR

- you need to ask DBA to declare a *link server* (***beware performance!***) :

Then you can access :

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM dbo.Table1 as localTable
, FROM **LINKEDSERVER**.NORTHWIND.DBO.CATEGORIES
```

- LINKEDSERVER : created by DBA
- NORTHWIND.DBO.CATEGORIES : suppose you wanted data from category table in Northwind database.

**Don't forget to specify schema** when querying.